# JavaScript split() method resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split, text-files

I'm working on a simple program that will select a random string from an array.

I started with a predefined array, but about halfway through wondered if it wouldn't be simpler (or more elegant) to use a `text file (.txt)`, since I have a bit over 1000 items.

I found this solution here (for which I take no credit) and it is working for me...

```
function readTextFile(file) {
    var items = [];
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status === 0)
            {
                var items = rawFile.responseText.split('\n');
                alert(items[0]);
            }
        }
    };
    rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile('source.txt');
```

...to an extent.

I want the `array items[]` to contain one line per item. In other words I want to split per new line. However, all array items are undefiend after `items[0]` when I use `split('\n')`.

`items[0]` in the example above becomes the first sentence, so that much is correct. If I want to `alert items[1]` I get undefined.

If I use some other split point, such as `split('')`, it works correctly, separating each character per item ONLY until the line breaks, after which point I get undefined again.

Let's say the first line of the `.txt is "asd"`:
so 'asd' is defined in array as :

```
items[0] = 'a'
items[1] = 's'
items[2] = 'd'
items[3] = undefined
```

This is what I would get. Where am I wrong?

Contents of text file:

```
asfe
asdasdasd
asdasd

fgfg
```

Comment: I would use the array, count how many items in it, and then choose a random number between that amount and use it to call that array item.

Comment: Oh, the random selection is not yet implemented but don't think I would have problems there (yet). For now I just want to guarantee all my array items are correct. Thank you though!

Comment: How you save that file? What is your text editor? I suspect the newline character isn't really `\n`.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: I suspect that too. I simply opened Notepad in Windows 7, typed some gibberish and saved it. Nothing else.

Comment: @Hubologist so that's weird, as it worked for me just fine. By the way, you need to run the code via IIS, running it as a local file (i.e. double clicking the HTML file in Windows Explorer) won't work.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: sorry would you clarify that? Should it simply not work at all by running locally? I'm using Netbeans IDE and I run the code through it (it opens in Chrome). The code, in essence, works. I do get correct array items up until the first line break where I start getting undefined.

Comment: @Hubologist no. In order for things like AJAX to work smoothly, as far as I can tell, you should use a web server. Windows 7 should come with IIS, you just need to enable it via Add/Remove Windows Features.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding a String cast:

`var items = String(rawFile.responseText).split('\n');`

Answer (score 2):

After some messing around with this I believe the problem is with your text editor that save the file with line breaks consisting of `\r` instead of `\n`, maybe Unix based server?

Anyway, you can replace those and it should work:

```
var rawText = rawFile.responseText;
rawText = rawText.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
rawText = rawText.replace(/\n\r/g, "\n");
rawText = rawText.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
var items = rawText.split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because there's a blank row at the end of the `responseText`. Try using [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
var items = rawFile.responseText.trim().split('\n');
```

Comment: Could you please post the contents of `source.txt`?

Comment: The issue isn't with a blank line at the end of the file, but rather at the third index. Not a lot you can do about that to avoid it creeping in with JavaScript. Rather, you'll need to handle `undefined` values in the array.